# Best Config / Instance for Magento 1.3 on AWS EC2 RDS

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hello We have a dedicated server currently and wanting to move Magento to Amazon Web services.

We have

1) Magento 1.3CE  ( will be upgraded in the next few months to multi store ).  It uses APC cache currently and CDN.

2) 1500-2500 sessions per day : Typically 10-20 concurrent users and fortnightly 20-70 concurrent users for a few hours - very occasionally 200 concurrent users.

3) 10 wordpress sites - latest versions ( one integrated with Magento )

4) All running MYSQL , PHP 5.4

We want

```
1) Room to Grow
2) Use RDS
3) Enough grunt to be very responsive
4) SSD
```

I have narrowed instances down to m3 , c3 or r3 AWS instances.

Question : Which instance is recommended - and ( assuming UBUNTU  ) what default should I load ;  some sort of LAMP Stack ( should it be without MYSQL because I am using RDS? ) .  any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks so much for your time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try something you think is big enough, and if it isn't enough, upgrade it to a larger size. No reason to provision more than you need at the time. You shouldn't worry about "room to grow" when it only takes a few minutes to upgrade your server to a larger size. Also you should be looking at the latest generation of AWS instance types, m4, instead of m3. It sounds like you are hosting this somewhere already, so how does your current server compare to the available AWS instance types? That should give you some sort of clue as to what size to start with.

Also, EC2 instance size and RDS instance size are two different choices you will have to make.

Comment: Thanks - any ideas around config ( in terms of LAMP stack or other ways of short cutting a full install )..?